# Mixing static and dynamic items in react-native-swiper

Tags: react-native

I saw, that for dynamic items was added. It's is working well. Using multiple static items is working well too. But if I have one static item and multiple dynamic items the swiper only shows the static + one of the dynamic. So I always get two "pages".

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
<Swiper height={window.width}>
    <View><Text>x</Text></View>

    {this.media().map((media) => {
        return <View key={media.id}><Image
            source={{uri: media.path}}  
            style={styles.restaurantImage} /></View>;
    })}
</Swiper>



media() {
    return Object.keys(this.props.media).map(key => this.props.media[key])
}
```

Comment: Two solve this problem you can start with reading [ask] and then continue with reading [mcve].

Comment: Basically something like on the code you shared should work. It might about the return of `this.media()` or styles, not sure. Also, you have `key` on wrong component, it should be on parent `<View />` not `<Image />`

Comment: I've added the media() function. It returns 3 items. The key was on the wrong element because of testing. I've added it to View now.